# sql cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i am trying to create a table that uses a foreign key from another table an i keep getting the error:"1215 cannot add foreign key constraint "

i checked and it says the following:

> "Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
>   referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
>   in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
>   Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
>   tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
>   cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
>   See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition."

below is my sql code:

```
show engine innodb status;
CREATE TABLE trainee (
    traineeid bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(20),
    lname VARCHAR(20),
    id INT(9),age INT, 
PRIMARY KEY (traineeid));

CREATE TABLE trainer(
    trainerid bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
    fname VARCHAR(20),lname VARCHAR(20),
    id INT(9), 
PRIMARY KEY (trainerid));

CREATE TABLE club(
    clubid bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
    clubname VARCHAR(20), 
PRIMARY KEY(clubid));

CREATE TABLE team(
    teamid bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
    teamname VARCHAR(20),
    clubid bigint unsigned,
INDEX(clubid), 
FOREIGN KEY (clubid) REFERENCES club (clubid)
 ON DELETE SET NULL
 ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
PRIMARY KEY(teamid));

CREATE TABLE competition(
    competitionid bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
    competitiondate DATE,
    competitionname VARCHAR(40), 
PRIMARY KEY(competitionid));

CREATE TABLE trainertoteam(
    trainerid bigint unsigned not null,
    teamid bigint unsigned not null, 
PRIMARY KEY(teamid,trainerid), 
INDEX(trainerid), 
FOREIGN KEY (trainerid) REFERENCES trainer (trainerid)
 ON DELETE set null
 ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
INDEX(teamid), 
FOREIGN KEY (teamid) REFERENCES team (teamid)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

could you help me to find what is the error?

i know the error is when creating trainertoteam table

Comment: Looks like you will need to create a [composite index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on `trainer (trainerid,fname,lname)` (fields in *that* order!), which matches the foreign key reference.

Comment: Or, better yet, leave the `fname` and `lname` fields out of the `trainertoteam` relation. A trainer should be identified/referenced by his ID (= primary key) only.

Comment: i removed the fname and lname in the trainer to team table and it still doesn't work

Comment: What's the exact error message now and which of the statements fails?

Comment: i removed the fname and lname and changed the on delete and it worked but if i would want to remain the fname and lname how should i do that?

Comment: In that case, refer to my first comment.

Comment: i read it and tried what you suggested and it still didn't work can you give an example for a composite index? because i read the link and did exactly that

Comment: Should be as easy as `create unique index someIx on trainer (trainerid,fname,lname)`, I think.

Comment: Of course, you will have to create the index *before* creating the (table with the) foreign key contraint referring to it.

Comment: @HannoBinder binder what i did is:       CREATE TABLE trainertoteam(
        trainerid bigint unsigned not null,fname varchar(20),lname varchar(20),
        teamid bigint unsigned not null, 
    PRIMARY KEY(teamid,trainerid), 
    INDEX(trainerid,fname,lname), 
    FOREIGN KEY (trainerid,fname,lname) REFERENCES trainer (trainerid,fname,lname)
     ON DELETE set null
     ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
    INDEX(teamid), 
    FOREIGN KEY (teamid) REFERENCES team (teamid)
     ON DELETE CASCADE
     ON UPDATE CASCADE);

Comment: Maybe a problem is before in creating `team` table, because column `clubid` in `club` table is not null, and in `team` table is null?